# Angular 2: create divs dynamically

Tags: html, angular, for-loop

I want to create divs on the fly (with bootstrap classes) in angular 2 based on a value I receive from the database. For example, I get 6 categories from the db, so that would translate on screen into 3 div.row having 2 div.col-md-6 inside. How can I write a for loop in Angular to do this?

edit: or to ask this otherwise, how can I use ngFor to create elements only on odd indices?

Comment: Did you try to use *ngFor?

Comment: How can I create only 3 div.row with ngFor though when iterating till 6?

Comment: create a pipe that split into columns ?

Comment: Can you write the correct syntax of the ngFor with the pipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fully answer your question it is necessary to see your object/array structure.

Anyway, here's how you would check if its odd:

```js
<div *ngFor="let x of anyArray; let even = even; let odd = odd">
   <div *ngIf="odd">odd</div>
   <div *ngIf="even">even</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

with your given structure its easy todo:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      <div *ngFor="let row of data" class="any class you want here">
        <div *ngFor="let item of row" class="any class you want">
          {{ item.id + ': ' + item.name }}
        </div>

        <br /> <!-- just to demonstrate a visual effect here! :) -->
      </div>

    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;

  data = [
    [{id:1,name:'name1'},{id:2,name:'name2'}],
    [{id:3,name:'name3'},{id:4,name:'name4'}],
    [{id:5,name:'name5'},{id:6,name:'name6'}]
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/XjS25h19Rjny4N6OVhN1?p=preview

Or using your first data approach and using a pipe:

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/8P15VdkWS4Oy02Ezevpp?p=preview

Comment: Simply I have an array with some custom objects, [{id:1,name:'name1'},{id:2,name:'name2'},{id:3,name:'name3'},{id:4,name:'name4'},{id:5,name:'name5'},{id:6,name:'name6'}]

Comment: I think I will need to change this into [[{id:1,name:'name1'},{id:2,name:'name2'}],[{id:3,name:'name3'}‌​,{id:4,name:'name4'}‌​],[{id:5,name:'name5'}‌​,{id:6,name:'name6'}‌​]] to save me from the headache

Comment: With your second array in array approach its easier, thats true! :)

Comment: your welcome! feel free to ask any other stuff, too.