# Angular 2 : Create Div on the Fly by Iterating Over Objects

Tags: angular

I would like to create div's on the fly by iteration over the Objects in the JSON variable.
**I know how to create it if I had to iterate over Array of Arrays but not on Objects**

My JSON is following

```
{  
    "physics" : {  
        "subjectCode": 101,  
        "subjectName": "Physics",  
        "sectionA": 200,  
        "sectionB": 500,  
        "sectionC": 158,  
    },  
    "chemistry" : {  
        "subjectCode": 102,  
        "subjectName": "Chemistry",  
        "sectionA": 200,  
        "sectionB": 500,  
        "sectionC": 158,  
    },  
    "maths" : {  
        "subjectCode": 102,  
        "subjectName": "Maths",
        "sectionA": 200,  
        "sectionB": 500,  
        "sectionC": 158  
    }
}
```

In my Component I am storing the data in **data** variable

```
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {  
    data: object;  
    public dataArray: any;  
    constructor(private _data: Data) { }  
    ngOnInit() {  
        this._data.getData()  
            .subscribe(data => {  
                console.log(data);  
                for (let key in data) {  
                    console.log(data[key]);  
                    this.dataArray = [];  
                    this.dataArray.push(data[key]);  
                }  
            });  
    }
}
```

How to create 3 div - **physics, chemistry and maths** according to this JSON on  the fly.
I am getting all the properties of the Objects but not the Objects itself.
The output is like this

```
{  
"subjectCode": 102,  
"subjectName": "Maths",  
"sectionA": 200,  
"sectionB": 500,  
"sectionC": 158  
}
```

instead of physics, chemistry, maths

Typescript provides **for..of statements** 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html

I know some might flag it as a duplicate of
 [Angular 2: create divs dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42368844/angular-2-create-divs-dynamically)

But kindly help me. I am a newbie and have wasted a lot of time in this.

Cannot find any answer with easy explanation.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/q/45605257/5706293 ?

Comment: I tried following this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/45667731/7445094 but it is throwing an error after the first loop itself.   
**Component.ts**
data: object;
  public dataArray: any[];
  constructor(private _data: Data) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._data.getData()
      .subscribe(data => {
        // this.data = data;
        console.log(data);
        for (let key in data) {
          console.log(data[key]);
          this.dataArray.push(data[key]);
        }
      });

  }
And it gives the following error **ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**

Comment: And? Can you show what you tried in your question?

Comment: @echonax just comment. Kindly, check it.

Comment: Please don't write code blocks in the comment section. It is hard to read as you'd appreaciate. Can you edit your question with it?

Comment: Yes. Doing it. Give me 30 seconds.

Comment: Where do you initialize `this.dataArray`?

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: That's not initialization, that's a decleration. You are declaring that there is a field named `dataArray` and its type is any. It needs to be something like `this.dataArray = [];`

Comment: @echonax I just update the question with the output. Instead of physics, chemistry and maths in different div's, I got the output of Maths property in single div.
I dont have enuf reputation. Cant move to chat. :/

Comment: Its done. Thanks I was declaring it inside the for loop Declared this.dataArray = []; outside the for loop and got the expected output. @echonax Thanks.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :-)

Comment: Just one last thing. The output is coming in double quotes. How to remove them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would do something like this:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of dataArray">{{ item.subjectName }}</div>
  `
})
export class AboutComponent implements OnInit {
  // your class implementation...
}
```